# V2 authentication URL not gets called after upgrading forge-apis npm to 0.9.6

Tags: oauth-2.0, autodesk-forge

`

Previously I was using v1 authentication with three-legged. Now it's declared from Autodesk that onwards the 30th [image]of October it will decommission hence I updated the forge-apis npm to 0.9.6 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/forge-apis/v/0.9.6)
and @types of forge-apis to 0.9.0 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/forge-apis/v/0.9.0 )

I have updated the library even though  the URL gets called v1.

**The code snippet in node-js :**

```
import * as ForgeAPI from 'forge-apis';

let oa3Legged = new ForgeAPI.AuthClientThreeLegged(appConfig.accAuth.clientId,appConfig.accAuth.clientSecret,appConfig.accAuth.callback,['data:read', 'bucket:read', 'viewables:read', 'data:search'],true);

token = await oa3Legged.refreshToken(token).catch((error) => { aiLogger.traceError('error in refresh token method',{error});});
```

Please help me out what wrong I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a cache issue on your side. If you run `which npm` it probably will point out to the local path where an older version is available and it is the one using.

What I did is the following:

1. Check the path with `which npm`
2. Remove `/usr/local/bin/npm` by `$ sudo rm /user/local/bin/npm`
3. This will remove npm from your environment and you need to install it again.
4. I also removed Node to get a fresh version of it. Repeat step 1 and 2 but replace npm with node.
5. Install Node again I used `brew install node` but you can do it from the website.
6. When checking `which node` or `which npm` it will now have a new path.
7. Delete the forge-apis folder from the Cached location.
8. Run `npm install` so a fresh version of it will be installed.

This will guarantee you are using the latest npm of the platform.

Comment: Thank you for your response !
The first thing to say is that I am using Windows OS, not Linux.
I have newly installed node 18 and npm supported in this version is 9.5.0.
I  used the command npm cache clean --force but still pointing with the v1 URL of ACC.
After your recommendation uninstalled and deleted all the relevant folders with NPM and Node and then installed node18.15.0 (with NVM) also deleted the folder forge-apis from node modules and installed again the forge-api 0.9.6 but still pointing to the V1 URL while doing 3-legged refresh token.

Comment: We will be focusing on releasing the new SDK's for both Nodejs and .NET with the included functionality soon. We also have extended the date for the V1 migration so your services will not be affected. We are working on the updates to the announcement. As soon as we have the new OAuth SDKs we will share it in our blog post and newsletter.

Answer (score 0):

For using OAuth v2, you must change the Class from `AuthClientThreeLegged` to `AuthClientThreeLeggedV2` after upgrading to forge-apis v0.9.6

```js
let client = new AuthClientThreeLeggedV2(client_id, client_secret, callback_url, scopes);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! After a discussion with @Jaime, I highlighted this issue too because I found one class is written for the V2 APIs in node modules of forge-apis(0.9.6) but when I tried to make a call ( like this new AuthClientThreeLeggedV2) it showed not found. We are using latest typescript(https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/forge-apis/v/0.9.0 ) and latest forge-apis npm(https://www.npmjs.com/package/forge-apis/v/0.9.6).
This same issue I have already raised with Jaime in our Zoom call.

Comment: I have also attached the images for the same in main thread

Answer (score 0):

Now the latest updates include support for v2 authentication. Once I updated the npm lib of @types/forge-apis to 0.9.1 we can use the class of v2 authentication.

let client = new AuthClientThreeLeggedV2(client_id, client_secret, callback_url, scopes);

so we need to update the below library in order to use v2 authentication.
1.https://www.npmjs.com/package/forge-apis/v/0.9.6
2.https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/forge-apis/v/0.9.1

Comment: Hi Rahul, `@types/forge-apis` it's a community-contributed library, which can be found in https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/forge-apis/index.d.ts Feel free to create a pull request to add the missing functions.